# flutter_spinning_wheel Evitar que gire manualmente

Tags: flutter, dart

estoy usando [Spinning wheel](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_spinning_wheel) y trato de que la rueda no gire manualmente, sino sólo cuando se pulsa el botón. ¿Alguien logró hacerlo?

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es extraer el widget en local y quitar el gesture detector para que no detecte cuando deslizas manualmente.

Comment: Intenté usar GestureDetector pero me daba error, al final lo conseguí con AbsorbPointer, me contesto a mi propia pregunta con el código arreglado. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente lo conseguí arreglar usando Absorber Pointer. Aquí el código completo.

```
class _RuletaPageState extends State <RuletaPage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{
  final StreamController _dividerController  = StreamController<int>();
  final                  _wheelNotifier      = StreamController<double>();

  double _generateRandomVelocity() => (Random().nextDouble() * 6000) + 2000;
  double _generateRandomAngle()    => Random().nextDouble() * pi * 2;

  dispose() {
    _dividerController.close();
    _wheelNotifier.close();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: 100,width: 500,),
          AbsorbPointer(
              child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    SpinningWheel(
                      Image.asset('assets/ruleta_colores.jpg'),
                      initialSpinAngle: _generateRandomAngle(),
                      canInteractWhileSpinning: false,
                      spinResistance: 0.2,
                      secondaryImage:Image.asset("assets/triangulo.png"),
                      secondaryImageHeight: 50,
                      secondaryImageWidth: 50,
                      width: 310,
                      height: 310,
                      dividers: 12,
                      onUpdate: _dividerController.add,
                      onEnd: _dividerController.add,
                      shouldStartOrStop: _wheelNotifier.stream,
                    ),
                    StreamBuilder(
                      stream: _dividerController.stream,
                      builder: (context, snapshot) => snapshot.hasData ? RouletteScore(snapshot.data) : Container(),
                    ),
                  ]
              )
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: new Text("GO"),
            onPressed: () => _wheelNotifier.sink.add(_generateRandomVelocity()),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
class RouletteScore extends StatelessWidget {
  final int selected;
  final Map<int, String> labels = {
    1: 'NARANJA',
    2: 'ROJO',
    3: 'MORADO',
    4: 'VIOLETA',
    5: 'VIOLETA OSCURO',
    6: 'AZUL',
    7: 'AZUL CLARO',
    8: 'VERDE',
    9 : "VERDE CLARO",
    10: "AMARILLO",
    11: "AMARILLO OSCURO",
    12: "NARANJA CLARO"
  };
  RouletteScore(this.selected);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text('${labels[selected]}',
        style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, fontSize: 24.0));
  }
}
```